# How do I get in the third person character view?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So, I can't get into third person character view. I am playing the Elder Scrolls V Skyrim on Xbox360, but when I'm in an open area (just to make sure there was enough room for the camera to move around) and press the right joystick down it doesn't work.

Any helpful ideas??

Comment: You need to sheathe your weapons

Comment: @Ben That's not a duplicate. That question is asking about the in-inventory "paper doll" feature (as in Oblivion). This is asking how to get into 3rd-person camera mode, an unrelated feature.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yes, however the answers also answer this one...

Comment: @Ben They only answer this question incidentally. Consider: if a mod adds the paper doll to the inventory and this becomes a widely-used mod, and then that becomes the accepted answer, then the top answer would be useless for answering this question. That's why duplicates should be exact, not "well, it looks close enough" — because different problems are different.

Comment: @Ben [The same answer doesn't mean that it's a duplicate](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7364/39891)

Answer (score 2):

**How to Activate 3RD Person Mode:** 

*Simply press the Right Stick Down (Or R3 if on PS3), and this will toggle between First and Third Person*

**What do I do if it doesn't work?**

- Activate the key when still, not when moving, attacking or performing any action

  - **(Not Normally Needed)**
- Sheath your weapons/spells. This will also allow you to look at the front of your character

  - **(Not Normally Needed)**

**What if that STIIL doesn't help?**

The issue is most probably occuring because of a fault in the motor sensor that detects the push of the Right Stick. Try with another controller, and see if that stops the problem.

Alternatively, try another game that you know uses the right stick push to do an action (e.g. COD/Battlefield push for Sprint) and see if it works there.

- If it does work there, there is an issue with your Skyrim and you should reinstall the game (deleted the game data files). To be sure, try the disc on another friends console and see if the problem persists there
- If it doesn't work there, there is an issue with either the controleer (very probable) or the console itslef (very unlikely). Try your controller on a friends console and see if the button works on their games **on their console**. If it does, then there is an issue with the XBOX receiving the input. If it failed on **your friends console** like **your own**, then its a controller problem.